# what are the differences between nowjs and meteor?

Tags: meteor, nowjs-sockets

I saw they were both like this:
you write one code and then can run in client and server, so could someone tell me the key differences between them?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at some of the examples on both their sites but the main advantages/extra features of Meteor are:
- Code seems more modular with smart packages
- Your site will be fully reactive in that changes on the database and code will refresh the clients view automatically
- It doesn't seem clear how NowJS is storing the data on the server, on Meteor its with MongoDB with the future the ability to swap out to different DB types

There are many more advantages and probably some disadvantages but I am guessing these will be ironed out as Meteor is getting a fair bit of contribution.